# Standardized directory for user-specific app data

Tags: linux, ubuntu, files, configuration

I know all applications store user-specific data in the `$HOME` directory, but it seems that (some) more "modern"/recent applications has a preference for stuffing their settings and application data in a subdir of the `$HOME/.config` directory.

Is there a system to this that prevents naming collisions and such? Is it perhaps Gnome specific and requires registering some kind of namespace? I know there is a standard to file system layout on Unix, but it does not seem to describe user-specific data in any deeper granularity.

Usually, I would just create a `$HOME/.my-script-config`, but thought it would be interesting to know if another approach is wanted.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a system to this that prevents naming collisions and such?

None that I'm aware of. As a programmer you just google whether your application name is unique.

`$HOME/.config` is the new(est) standard because people realized that having all the application files right in the user home directory is not sensible. Besides the said files could be split between configuration (`.config`), temporary cache (`.cache`) and application data (`.local/share`) to ease backing up (the last two directories are not worth backing up).

> but it does not seem to describe user-specific data in any deeper granularity.

It does, check this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1151796).

Comment: I would imagine there is actually a system that ensures that no 2 packages in the main repository of the OS create the same file. I don't know this, but it seems like a reasonable test. Are you sure no such thing exists, at least in systems that work with repositories?

Comment: RPM/DEB surely won't allow to install two different packages sharing the same name - other than that I've not heard anything. The presented question/problem however is completely different.

Comment: I was just thinking that there probably is "a system [...] that prevents naming collisions", at least when talking about packages of a specific distribution. For example, if one package tries to install a file already installed by another package, apt and pacman will complain. So there's two systems. And I expect all other packaging managers have equivalent ones.